# Альбом пользователя

Tags: jquery, php, html5-history-api, javascript, html5

Здравствуйте!   Есть задача организовать личную галерею пользователя.
То есть заходя на страницу пользователя я получаю некий массив с данными о фотках пользователя (на примере пользователя 5):

> ```
> [id] => 1 [user_id] => 5 [description] => фотка 1 [link] => /photo/1.png  
> [id] => 8 [user_id] => 5 [description] => фотка 2 [link] => /photo/8.png  
> [id] => 11 [user_id] => 5 [description] => фотка 3 [link] => /photo/11.png
> ```

Имея этот массив нужно сделать нечто подобное:

> http://s42.radikal.ru/i098/1209/f9/215535b7de84.png

Но нужно чтобы при серфинге изображений изменялась адресная строка в зависимости от основного фото, без перезагрузки страницы. А так же чтобы при заходе на эту ссылку сторонним пользователем отображалась фотография именно та, от которой зависит адресная строка, подобное сейчас реализовано в Вконтакте.

**Вопрос:** Какая литература(статьи, готовые решения с открытым кодом или т. п.)  помогла бы мне разобраться во всём этом?

P.S. Прошу прощения за кашу в посте, просто уже в голове всё перепуталось...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сегодня наткнулся на эту [тему](http://www.nulled.cc/threads/228626/), возможно будет полезна.

Comment: Спасибо, кое что получилось из темы извлечь.